# Strange casting in VB in Math.Pow

Tags: c#, .net, pow

This code is working fine

```
Dim bc As Long = Math.Pow(36, ((IBase36.Length - 1) - i))
```

**! Under VB Math.Pow return DOUBLE data type.**

When I convert it into C# I have got

```
long bc = Math.Pow(36, ((IBase36.Length - 1) - i));
```

And I have a cast syntax issue.

How it could be resolved?

Comment: You gotta watch out for code like this.  Long has 19 significant digits, a double only has 15.  When the value gets large enough, you can easily be off by one due to truncation.  At least add 0.5 so this can't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long bc = (long)Math.Pow(36, ((IBase36.Length - 1) -i));
```

() is the [cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa) in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Probably in VB you have [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) **Off** or not declared at all (Default Off)

From MSDN

```
Visual Basic allows conversions of many data types to other data types. 
Data loss can occur when the value of one data type is converted to a data type with 
less precision or smaller capacity. A run-time error occurs if such a narrowing 
conversion fails. Option Strict ensures compile-time notification of these narrowing 
conversions so they can be avoided.
```

So I will change the VB code

```
Option Strict On

Dim bc As Long = CType(Math.Pow(36, ((IBase36.Length - 1) - i)), Long)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Pow` has the return type `double`, which in C# cannot be implicitly converted to `long`, so it must be done explicitly via typecast. I'm not fluent in VB.NET, but the conversion rules may be less strict there.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you gotta tell the compiler Math.Pow is a long or double type if you want a result.

Check this out in a console app.

```
int value = 2;
string power = "6";
Console.WriteLine("" + (long)Math.Pow(value, (Convert.ToInt16(power) - 1)));
Console.ReadKey();
```